# How to shift function (like RotateRight) in the y direction?

Tags: fourier-analysis, rotation

I'd like to shift my graph so the periodogram is centered.

I was able to rotate the original using Rotate Right, but now I can't shift the graph in the y dimension.

Thank you for your help!

```
ListPlot3D[RotateRight[PDG01, Round[dm/2]]]
```

[image: Plots]

Comment: Also, try `ListPlot3D[ list , PlotRegion->All]` to prevent the plot from cutting off some values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve the desired result by doing the following:

```
rotateX=RotateRight[PDG01, Round[dm/2]];
rotateXY=Transpose[RotateRight[Transpose[rotateX], Round[dm/2]]];
ListPlot3D[rotateXY]
```

PS:

Since your x- and y-dimensions are of different length, you'll have to adjust the `Round[dm/2]` value during y-rotation appropriately.